# Filter items from Firebase branch (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, firebase

Current user in App tap the Like button on post (audio record) from another user and it appears in `likes` branch in Firebase. There is another branch `records`, where all records from each users exist.

I've got a Firebase structure
 [image]

Blue: current userID,
Green: another userID,
Red: recordID.

I need to display on my ViewController only liked records (red line), but with my code I've got all records from another user (green line). How to display only liked records (red line)?

```
 fileprivate func fetchRecordsWithUser(user: User2){

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("records").child(user.uid)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
            guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] else { return }
            let record = Records(user: user, dictionary: dictionary)
            self.records.append(record)
            self.records.sort(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                return p1.creationDate.compare(p2.creationDate) == .orderedDescending
            })
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        })
    }) { (err) in
        print ("Faild to fetch records:", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to retrieve this users liked recordID's? So you want iterate over the nodes within */sqpj...* and get the child's child node - so that would be *-LU8V* and *-L_6E*? Oh - and generally is a good idea to include your Firebase structure as text in your question so if we want to use it in an answer we can copy/paste instead of retyping.

Comment: Or do you want to get all the child node keys within the */records/uid/* node. You code seems to indicate the latter but it's a bit unclear.

Comment: @Jay I want to show in LikeTableViewController list with records  -LU8V and -L_6E, but these records with all details (title, lenght, URL etc.) are in `records` branch. I can't  retrieve record with ID -LU8V from user's (ID 843QU...) from records list, I can retrieve only whole records list. And yes, much easier to have JSON in text not screenshot, but it's too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unclear on the question but let me give this a try

Lets's start with a structure like in the question, using simpler data.

```
likes
   uid_0
      uid_1
         record_0: true
      uid_2
         record_1: true
   uid_1
      uid_0
         record_3: true
```

I believe the object is the get the values record_0, record_1 and record_3 so the code to do that is:

```
func printRecordIds() {
    var recordIdArray = [String]()
    let likesRef = self.ref.child("likes")
    likesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let allLikes = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for likeSnap in allLikes {
            let uid = likeSnap.key
            print(uid)
            let uidLikes = likeSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            for childLike in uidLikes {
                let childUid = childLike.key
                print("  child uid: \(childUid)")
                let childRecords = childLike.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                for child in childRecords {
                    let recordId = child.key
                    print("    recordId: \(recordId)")
                    recordIdArray.append(recordId)
                }
            }

            for r in recordIdArray {
                print(r)
            }
        }
    })
```

and the output

```
uid_0
  child uid: uid_1
    recordId: record_0
  child uid: uid_2
    recordId: record_1
record_0
record_1
uid_1
  child uid: uid_0
    recordId: record_3

record_0
record_1
record_3
```

So the output shows the data we are reading in per node so you can see the flow and then the array, populated with the record id's.